# Creating a new page in a web application stuck in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I'm working on a web application, where a user can create web pages by using drag-and-drop widgets. So I was trying to introduce this feature where a user is redirected to the last page he saved when he opens this application, instead of showing a blank canvas as it does now.

So I was able to do it after I introduced a function in the **js** file that loads the application to redirect it to last used page after loading, but the problem is when the user clicks on create new(if he wants to work on a new project), it again redirects to the same last used page instead of showing a blank canvas. It's stuck in a loop not allowing me to create a new web page. But I can still open some other existing pages.

The js file does these things:

- It resets the widget connections
- Has functions to open existing ones, create new file show preview of the page created etc.
- To this I added a function, which puts the url of the last saved page to redirect it as soon as the user loads the application.

When you click on new, it again wipes out the url and executes the above js file, so now it redirects back to the last saved page when it loads again because of the function I added.

I tried introducing a boolean variable which is set to true initially and the page is redirected back to last saved page, only if this boolean variable is true. Now I'm setting this variable to false if the user clicks on **createNew** page, so that this function isn't executed. But this variable is again set to true when I reload the page.

```
var not_create_new = true;
......
if(user clicks on createNew in the menu) create_new = false;
.......
if(not_create_new) {
    alert(not_create_new); //this's always showing true even if I click on createNew menu option
    restore(file_name); // which I get from the server
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How would I know what's wrong? Or rather, how could I? There is nothing for us to work with.

Comment: Please share your code. Probably, you should find a way to not trigger that js function when user is trying to "create new".